Source code of AT&T Unix System V release 3.2 for i386
I'm looking for the source code of AT&T Unix System V release 3.2 (SVR3) for i386, released in 1988. I wasn't able to find a copy online, and I wasn't able to figure out where I could buy it.
I've found:

Precompiled releases (without the source) of SVR3 for i386. For example: https://winworldpc.com/product/pc-ix/interactive-unix-386-2x and http://bitsavers.org/bits/ATT/SYSV_386/
Precompiled releases (without the source) of SVR4 for i386. For example: https://archive.org/details/intel-unix-sv-r4-v2
Source of SVR3 for 3B2 (not i386): https://github.com/ryanwoodsmall/oldsysv/tree/master/sysvr3
Source of SVR4 for i386: https://github.com/ryanwoodsmall/oldsysv/tree/master/sysvr4/svr4 and https://github.com/mamccollum/svr4-386-src (SVR4 3.0)


Take a look at this.  I have no way verify its authenticity.  https://github.com/jacklin9/UNIX-SVR3.2-Src

@SteveMathwig: https://github.com/jacklin9/UNIX-SVR3.2-Src is for 3B2, not for i386. If it was for i386, there would be an i386 directory in https://github.com/jacklin9/UNIX-SVR3.2-Src/tree/main/usr/src/cmd/sgs/as
